# What do 'physically real' means in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, virtual-particles

Unlike classical physic, anything that is experimentally observable is physically real in quantum mechanics at least that's how I interpret. So can I say graviton is not real because we cannot experimentally detect any physical properties from it just like the virtual particles? Higgs boson was recently discovered so it is real only recently? What do physically real actually means in quantum mechanic anyway? Sounds like because engineering can't catch up to theory we will say they are not real? I'm confused...

Comment: This is an ontological question and is better suited for the philosophy stack exchange. Moreover it is opinion-based. E.g. one could argue that observables are only perceived by us. There is no reason to assume that what is being observed really exists and is not just a manifestation of our perception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unlike classical physic, anything that is experimentally observable is physically real in quantum mechanics

This is true for both quantum mechanics and classical mechanics. If you can experimentally observe something or a physical phenomena that can be detected, then it is real.

> So can I say graviton is not real because we cannot experimentally detect

We can say we have a hypothesis that seems to suggest [gravitons](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviton) are real, but we cannot confirm this without an actual observation of gravitons.

> just like the virtual particles?

They are termed [virtual particles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle) because their lifetime and energy are constrained by the energy/time uncertainty relation. This lifetime is extremely small, hence the term virtual. Their existence is not permanent like the case for other particles.

> Higgs boson was recently discovered so it is real only recently?

This is exactly the same situation as above for gravitons only for the Higgs particle, we have already detected it. It is real, and prior to it’s detection, it was hypothesised.

> What do physically real actually means in quantum mechanic anyway?

It means it is physically measurable or detectable. It is tangible, and corresponds to what are callled [Hermitian operators](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint) in quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

*Objective reality* is the world existing independently on our consciousness and perception. That is the things exist (or not) regardless of whether we know about them, able to measure them, and regardless of what mathematical model we use to describe them.

Obviously, we have no way to know whether something is real without measuring it. We can say that the probability density, $|\psi(x)|^2$ is real, because it is measurable in principle, whereas the wave function iself $\psi(x)$ is not real, since it cannot be measured. Thus, in quantum mechanics we have alternative mathematical approaches (matrix mechanics, wave mechanics, etc.) which give equally correct mathematical predictions. Whereas in classical physics one assumes that everything can be in principle precisely measured, in quantum mechanics we accept that this is not the case, and that our knowledge about how things really work cannot go beyond of what is actually measurable.

In the context of the OP: *Graviton* is conjectured mathematically, but we cannot say whether it is really exist, unless we find a way to measure it. On the other hand, the Higgs boson has been proven to actually exist. It ahs not been any more or less real before we have measured it, but our knowledge aboutw hat is real or not has change since then.